# css градиент прямоугольник

Tags: html, css

Необходимо сделать фон блока таким образом

[image: Как необходимо сделать]

Думаю это возможно сделать через функцию linear gradient у background. Но получается только всегда в одну сторону, например

```css
.space {
  padding: 100px;
}

.bg_right_top {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFD19C 80%, white 20% ), 
                linear-gradient(to left, #FFD19C 80%, white 20% );
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg_right_top space">

</div>
```

Один всегда перекрывает другой. Хотел бы узнать, как сделать так, чтобы выглядело как на картинке выше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного не в ту сторону думаете..
У вас есть такие свойства как [`background-position`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-position) и [`background-size`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size).
Сделайте так, чтобы ваша картинка начиналась от верхнего правого края (`background-position: top right;`) и при этом чтобы до противоположного края не хватало 20%, т.е. `background-size: 80% 80%;`.

Таким способом мы сможем разместить градиент:

```css
.bg {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, red) no-repeat top right / 80% 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Или же картинку:

```css
.bg {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/vwVxXlP.png') no-repeat top right / 80% 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

А вот с чистым цветом не особо получится, вариант использовать градиент:

```css
.bg {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue, blue) no-repeat top right / 80% 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```